# How to show Vector Layer created by v.clean GRASS tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, snapping

I have created vector layer using GRASS tool v.snap, which resulted in a vector layer as output. I want to display the vector layer in QGIS. How can i view the vector layer created by snap tool in QGIS that is created by GRASS tool. After search on internet i found that there is a button used to Add GRASS vector layer in QGIS plugin. But in my current version that is 2.18. I did not find a option for this.

Comment: Assuming you used the GRASS Tool inside QGIS, next to the _Run_ button there should be a _View output_ button. Clicking this should load the output into QGIS.

Comment: This is at the end of output. But i closed the results, and don't know how to add it in QGIS.

Comment: Try running `v.out.ogr` and select your output from the list of vector maps (which should include the output). This will export the GRASS vector layer into a shapefile which you can then load into QGIS.

Comment: I tried that and it created the shapefile. But ultimately i have to export it back to postgreSQL database, but that encountered the attributes problem. Previously it was resolved by viewing the output file in QGIS and the export it using DbManager of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Good thing there is the `v.out.ogr.pg` module which exports the vector map directly to PostgreSQL ;)

Comment: If it worked, you should consider posting an **answer** so that others in your situation could benefit :)